# Identity 2.0 deployment - shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My application is MVC5.  When I published the application on shared hosting server, I could not login and get this screen below.
However I can login on when I run the application on my local computer with same database connection pointing to the server database.
Has anyone had similar issue or seen this screen before?  Would appreciate your suggestions.
[image]

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960707/asp-net-mvc-weird-characters-in-error-page have any suggestions that help you?

Comment: Thank you Donnelle, however I did not use GZip in my application.

Comment: Jon Adams has what might be useful thoughts in the comments on that question.

Comment: If you use ctrl-shift-I you'll get Chrome Dev tools. Go to network tab and load your page then paste a copy of the request/response headers for your page. Also note that your shared hosting provider may have enabled gzip by default = lower bandwidth charges for them. Either way your content encoding will tell us what's what.

Comment: It is unlikely that Identity is causing this issue.